# Handling reagent bottles

Tags: home-experiment

I have done an experiment to prepare a standard solution. To keep this standard solution , I'm going to put it into a reagent bottle .

If this reagent bottle is clean but not dry , what must I do ?

my attempt is to use small amount of ethanol to absorb the water and throw away the ethanol and allow the rest to evaporate away. Is this the correct method if I were to only use ethanol ? If not what must I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Normally in a lab you will use acetone after ethanol.  Then you dry the bottle in hoven . At home, using only ethanol and a hairdryer can be an alternative.

However, especially without water sensitive materials, and perhaps having a standard solution in water, the main point is to "normalise" the bottle.

In other words you wash your bottle with a little amount of standards solution that you pour away.  And repeat this step at least 3 times.

As such, whatever is residual in your bottle, will already be standard solution.

This applies if the bottle is already reasonably clean, as in your case.